# Find out if a selected text is inside a input field or textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, selection, textselection

I am creating a chrome extension.

Whenever you select a text I add two buttons to the webpage adjacent to the selection.

In case the selection is inside a textarea or Input box, i don't want any action to take place.

Here is the code i am using currently

```
$(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
    var class1=e.target.nodeName;
    var class2=e.target.firstChild;
    console.log(class1);
    console.log(class2);
    if(class1=="INPUT" || class1=="TEXTAREA"){
    }
    else{
    var selectedtext=window.getSelection().toString();
    var chars=selectedtext.length;
if(chars>2){
    var posx=e.clientX;
    var posy=e.clientY;
    var scrollDepth=$(window).scrollTop();
    posy=posy+scrollDepth;
    var location=findSelectionCoords(posx,posy);
    create_Button(location);
}
}
});
```

Create button function is used to create the buttons.

If the user selects some text inside the text area/input box this function works, the console shows input/textarea.
But sometimes the textarea or input box gets selected also and then this function fails. In the class1, I get DiV in this case.

Can some one suggest a function that will work in all cases and detect if a text selection is inside a input or text area

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code, in which the alert message is shown only if the `mouseup` event came from element that is not `textarea` or `input` of type text.

EDITED CODE:

```js
$(function() {
    var isInputOrTextarea = false;
 $(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
        // On mousedown flag whether it was clicked in input or textarea
        if($(e.target).is("textarea,input[type=text]")) {
            isInputOrTextarea = true;
        }
    });    
 $(document).on("mouseup", function(e) {
        if($(e.target).is("textarea,input[type=text]") || isInputOrTextarea) {
            isInputOrTextarea = false;
            return;
        }
        isInputOrTextarea = false;
        alert("Not in text area or input");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="Lorem ipsum"/>
<textarea>
    Lorem ipsum
</textarea>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this code faces the same problem my code faces.  Try selecting the text and hit the border of the input field. You will get the message "Not in text area or input"

Comment: In browser are you trying it? What do you really want to achieve? Because it is working. The message "Not in text area or input" shows only, and only, if you are not in the input or textarea when you release the mouse button, does not matter if you touch the border of the input or not. So, do you want the opposite or what?

Comment: This is the problem, in some cases user makes a selection and his mouse leaves the input box, it naturally happens sometime. Then the alert message shows up. I do not want this to happen. Is there a function that can help with this

Comment: In what browser are you trying the sample? I the sample I supplied, I am not able to reproduce the behavior you described. I make selection in the input (or text area) while moving the cursor outside of the input (or textarea) then I release the mouse and the message does not display. So I do not understand how or where you are trying it.

Comment: I am trying the sample on chrome. The problem is exactly what you described in your 1st comment. When the mouse goes out of the textarea and then it is released, the alert message shows up

Comment: Hm, that's the problem. Only in chrome it's not working as expected. I am going to fix it.

Comment: So I edited the sample code. It's how chrome (and also opera - the engine) handles the `mouseup` event. There is only one solution, and that is on each `mousedown` do the same check and remember whether user initial `mousedown` was made in the `input` or `textarea` element, and take this flag into consideration in `mouseup` handler. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just in javascript, an example of how to weed out events from inside the inputs. It's a one liner.

```
document.onkeydown = function (ev) {
  switch (ev.key) {
    case 'ArrowRight':
      if (!ev.shiftKey && ['INPUT','TEXTAREA'].indexOf(ev.srcElement.nodeName) == -1)
        advance();
      break;
    default:
      console.log(ev.key);
  }
};
```